# I want to pass files and information from React to Spring

Tags: reactjs, spring, multipartform-data

I want to pass the file and information to `Spring` as data from `React`. But I get `Axios error 400`. Is there any problem with the `React` and `Spring` codes? I have little experience with `Spring`, so I'm unsure if I made it right. How can I hand over files and information? Any advice or solution, please? The language may be strange because it is written by a translator.

**react**

```
  const saveData = {
    boardWriter: sessionStorage.getItem("memberID"),
    boardTitle: title,
    boardContents: contents,
    boardFile: file,
  }
```

```
const write = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();

formData.append("boardWriter", sessionStorage.getItem("memberID"));
    
formData.append("boardTitle", title);
    
formData.append("boardContents", contents);
    
formData.append("boardFile", file);

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8080/api/board/write", saveData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        }
      })
      .then(res => res.data)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));}
```

**spring**

**controller**

```
@PostMapping("/write")
    public void save(@RequestParam BoardDTO boardDTO,
                     @RequestParam MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        
String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        
file.transferTo(new File(fileName));
        
boardDTO.setBoardFile(fileName);
        
boardService.save(boardDTO);
  
}
```

**repository**

```
public int save(BoardDTO boardDTO) {
        
return sql.insert("Board.save", boardDTO);
    
}
```

**service**

```
public int save(BoardDTO boardDTO) {
        
return boardRepository.save(boardDTO);
    
}
```

**mapper**

```
<mapper namespace="Board">

    <insert id="save" parameterType="board">
        insert into board(boardWriter, boardTitle, boardContents, boardFile)
        values(#{boardWriter}, #{boardTitle}, #{boardContents}, boardFile=#{boardFile})
    </insert>
```

Comment: Please include code as text, not images.

Comment: sorry. It's my first time using Stack Overflow, so I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar, but using Angular and Spring.

This is an example of the code in Angular that sends a request:

```
  runCase(runDetails?: RunDetails, dataDrivenFile?: File) {
    const formdata: FormData = new FormData();
    if (dataDrivenFile) {
      formdata.append('dataDrivenFile', dataDrivenFile);
    }
    if (runDetails) {
      formdata.append('runDetails', new Blob([JSON.stringify(runDetails)], {
        type: 'application/json'
      }));
    }

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      Accept: 'application/json'
    });

    return this.apiService.post(this.cloudConfigService.runCase(), formdata, headers);
  }
```

the content of this.apiService.post is this:

```
  post(path: string, body: any, customHeaders?: HttpHeaders): Observable<any> {
    return this.request(path, body, RequestMethod.Post, customHeaders);
  }

  private request(path: string, body: any, method = RequestMethod.Post, customHeaders?: HttpHeaders): Observable<any> {
    const req = new HttpRequest(method, path, body, {
      headers: customHeaders || this.headers,
      reportProgress: true,
      withCredentials: true
    });

    return this.http.request(req).pipe(
      filter(response => response instanceof HttpResponse),
      map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => response.body)
    );
  }
```

And this is an example of the code in Spring that accepts and processes that request:

```
@PostMapping(value = APIConfig.RUN_CASE_URL)
public ResponseEntity runCase(
        @RequestPart(value = "dataDrivenFile", required = false) MultipartFile dataDrivenFile,
        @RequestPart("runDetails") RunDetails runDetails
) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    runDetails.setDataDrivenFile(dataDrivenFile);

    runService.run(runDetails);
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In the "save" method of your controller, add `(value="boardFile")` to the "file" RequestParam just like below and try again.

```
@PostMapping("/write")
    public void save(@RequestParam BoardDTO boardDTO,
                     @RequestParam(value="boardFile") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the way I showed in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75768766/19622845) you can find more details on how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75774033/19622845), or if you prefer, you can follow your initial approach with a few small modifications:

Change this:

```
formData.append("boardFile", file);
```

to this:

```
formData.append("file", file);
```

Or, in Spring, change:

```
@RequestParam MultipartFile file
```

to either:

```
@RequestParam MultipartFile boardFile
```

or:

```
@RequestParam(value="boardFile") MultipartFile file
```

And on this line, instead of sending **saveData**, send **formData**:

```
 axios
      .post("http://localhost:8080/api/board/write", saveData, {
```

Change it to look like this:

```
 axios
      .post("http://localhost:8080/api/board/write", formData, {
```

Delete **@RequestParam** on this line in Spring:

```
public void save(@RequestParam BoardDTO boardDTO,
```

So it looks like this:

```
public void save(BoardDTO boardDTO,
```

This should make it work. It works for me when I copy your code and make these changes.