# I want to pass files and information from React to Spring (@RequestParam or @RequestPart)

Tags: reactjs, spring

Spring says no data found in @RequestParam I tried changing @RequestPart or value but it doesn't work. How can I make a connection? Thanks for any advice, solution

**react**

```
boardWriter: sessionStorage.getItem("memberID"),
boardTitle: title,
boardContents: contents,
boardFile: file,
}
```

```
formData.append("saveData", new Blob([saveData]), {
type: "application/json",
})  
formData.append("boardFile", file);

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8080/api/board/write", saveData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        }
      })
      .then(res => res.data)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

**controller**

```
@PostMapping("/write")
    public void save(@RequestPart("saveData") BoardDTO boardDTO,
                     @RequestPart(value = "boardFile") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        
String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        
file.transferTo(new File(fileName));
        
boardDTO.setBoardFile(fileName);
        
boardService.save(boardDTO);
  
}
```

**repository**

```
public int save(BoardDTO boardDTO) {
        
return sql.insert("Board.save", boardDTO);
    
}
```

**service**

```
public int save(BoardDTO boardDTO) {
        
return boardRepository.save(boardDTO);
    
}

**error**
400 http bad request
Required BoardDTO parameter 'boardDTO' is not present
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @RequestParam and @ModelAttribute annotations for DTO with file.
There is some other code because I reuse my code before wrote.
Focus how to get data at API endpoints.

Here is my example.

###### React

```js
    const formData = new FormData();
    const data = {
      boardWriter: "this is writer",
      boardTitle: 'this is title',
      boardContents: 'this is boardContents'
    }
    formData.append('boardFile', this.files[0]);
    formData.append('saveData', JSON.stringify(data))
    axios.post('http://localhost:8081/dto',
        formData,
        {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
```

###### Spring

```java
    @PostMapping(value = "/dto")
    public @ResponseBody
    String uploadFileInDto(@RequestParam("saveData") String saveData,
                           @RequestParam("boardFile") MultipartFile file) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        BoardDTO boardDTO = objectMapper.readValue(saveData, BoardDTO.class);
        System.out.println(saveData);
        System.out.println(boardDTO);
        System.out.println(file);
        return "upload success";
    }
```

[image]

### Better Way

I think this is the better way for management back-end code.

###### React

```js
    const formData = new FormData();
    const data = {
      boardWriter: "this is writer",
      boardTitle: 'this is title',
      boardContents: 'this is boardContents'
    }
    for (let key in data) {
      formData.append(key, data[key])
    }
    formData.append('boardFile', this.files[0]);
    axios.post('http://localhost:8081/dto-2',
        formData,
        {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
```

###### Spring

```java
    @PostMapping(value = "/dto-2")
    public @ResponseBody
    String uploadFileInDto(@ModelAttribute BoardDTO boardDTO,
                           @RequestParam("boardFile") MultipartFile file) {
        System.out.println(boardDTO);
        System.out.println(file);
        return "upload success";
    }
```

[image]

And you need to setter method for DTO.

```java
package blog.in.action.dto;

import lombok.*;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
public class BoardDTO {

    private String boardWriter;
    private String boardTitle;
    private String boardContents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
formData.append("saveData", new Blob([saveData]), {
type: "application/json",
})
```

to this:

```
    formData.append("saveData", new Blob([JSON.stringify(saveData)], {
        type: "application/json"
    }));
```

Also, it seems that you have mistakenly sent **saveData** instead of **formData** in the following code.

```
axios
  .post("http://localhost:8080/api/board/write", saveData, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    }
  })
```

Please change it to:

```
   axios
      .post("http://localhost:8080/api/board/write", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        }
      })
```

This should make everything work.